# Using a Webcam from NodeJS on a BeagleBone Black

Tags: node.js, beagleboneblack

I am looking for a NodeJS module that will work on a BBB (running Ubuntu), that can stream webcam images. It needs to be able to give me the images in a format that I can do image operations on (ability to get and set pixels).

I have been able to use command-line utilities to capture and save images from my camera (so I know it is compatible), but the only NodeJS libraries that I have found fail on build.

Does anyone know of a library that can stream images from a webcam like this?

Comment: Are you trying to capture images, or stream them with a video codec?  Can FFMPEG stream directly from your camera by chance?

Comment: I can do with either (streaming or capture), it really depends on what's easier. As for your other question, I don't know. How do you suggest I test this? As you probably can tell, I am no Linux expert.

Comment: I've only ever ran video capture with FFMPEG on Windows, so I'm not sure how it works on Linux... but on Windows, it's pretty easy to open a capture device, let it do all the codec work, and return raw data over STDOUT, which you can get in your Node.js app and send to some server.  The most light-weight way to do this (probab\ly good for the hardware you're running) would be MJPEG.  But, I don't know specifics of getting the capture working under Linux.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm a Windows guy too. I am discovering that there is absolutely no transferable skill between Linux and Windows... other than moving a mouse. I have been searching for a way to use FFMPEG or V4L2 from node, but have been unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try Motion.

```
sudo apt-get install motion
```

You can set it up quickly with few modifications in configuration.

Good Luck.

Comment: What kind of output would it give me?

Comment: It can output jpg. You can also configure Motion to be used as a motion detector, time-lapse sequence capture device or streaming web cam.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear, but I need the stream directly. I can't record to disk first.

Comment: You can configure it as RTSP live streaming server.